# PHP returns 0 rows whereas phpmyadmin returns 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

my code is

```
<?php 
include 'includes/config.php';  
 $fetch = "SELECT *
FROM `status_comments`
WHERE status_id =4
AND item_poster = 'LUcase'";
 echo $fetch;
    $runfetch = mysqli_query($link, $fetch) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while ($comments = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runfetch)){ echo "woot"; }
?>
```

im echoing $fetch as you can see, and i use whats echoed to query in phpmyadmin and it returns 1 row.
But however in php it returns 0 rows.
What can be the problem?

Comment: dropping the where clause ie "SELECT * FROM status_comments"
returns rows

Comment: You're sure that your script and phpmyadmin are using the same db right?

Comment: Do you have more than one database setup on your server? If so you might need to specify the database in your query, `SELECT * FROM mydatabase.status_comments`. It's possible that phpMyAdmin could be configured to connect to the correct database.

Comment: yes i am sure that phpmyadmin and my script is using the same database and table.

Comment: ... And you are using the same capitalisation in both cases? (BTW - Please post the output when running the PHP script without the where clause).

Comment: im sorry but i have no idea what you just asked @EdHeal

Comment: i.e. not using Lucase in one case, and LUcase in the other.

Comment: ok status_id was supposed to be 2, fixed that but still no rows. There are rows when i do query without variables, but with variables like this, no rows are returned $fetch = "SELECT * FROM status_comments WHERE item_poster = '$status_us' and status_id = ".$_GET['status_id'].""; When echoing $fetch, the both queries are exactly the same but no rows returned in the query with variables.

Comment: @MarshallMathews No no no.. you stated clearly that you copied/pasted (NO EDIT) the query from your debug into phpmyadmin and got different results. Where are these variables coming from?

Comment: try like this http://pastebin.com/xWFps9Ai

Comment: well i have two files with the same query, i created a seperate one for testing..and i mistyped the status_id @MikeB i corrected it to the one im looking for but no rows.

Variables are coming from data-attributes to jquery to php via $_GET

Comment: @MarshallMathews There is no reference to `$_GET` in your code... try the chat feature if you're unwilling to show your code and are expecting others to walk you through debug.

Comment: the $_GET is in the main script, this is just a simple paste.
i have the exact one here http://pastebin.com/JEDkdha8
Line 36 to 92.
Ignore the jquery... its not related to the issue at all, the jquery variables to this php file comes from another js file which is all very fine

Comment: @MarshallMathews - You say you get results when the where clause is removed. Try a where clause with just 'status_id=2' (or 4), then with a where clause 'item_poster = 'LUcase'. Just to humor me try the where clause item_poster = 'Lucase'. What do you get in each of those cases

Comment: Those return rows and so does this
 $fetch = "SELECT * FROM status_comments WHERE status_id=".$_GET['status_id']." AND item_poster='LUcase'";
Its the same but still query does not work with $status_us

but item_poster='$status_us' does not return rows.
doing a while loop i echoed $comments['item_poster'] and $status_us

Comment: @MarshallMathews - Remove all the GET stuff first. Get the select to work with constants (as per original question). Please try my suggestion above. This will find out what part of the where clause is not working.

Comment: status_id = 2 works
$status_id = $_GET['status_id'] works
item_poster = 'LUcase' works
item_poster = '$status_us' does not work.

Comment: Therefore the value of `$status_us` is incorrect. Find out its value before the select statement (`echo`?).

Comment: i do item_poster = 'LUcase' 
also item_poster = '$status_us'
And echo it out, its the same..

Comment: ok echoing out the query with $status_us
i noticed there is a space between LUcase and the closing single quote(')

SELECT * from status_comments where status_id = 2 and item_poster = 'LUcase '
This is why its not working, what can be the reason there is a space?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8228/discussion-between-marshall-mathews-and-ed-heal)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use mysqli_error() to indicate your sql error if there is.
Can you attach also your include php file?

Comment: There are no errors, just 0 rows being returned.
Also im using mysqli which is why im not using mysql_query